# Magento 2 catalog search with apostrophe not working

Tags: magento2.3, search, catalogsearch, advanced-search

When I search brand name like L'Occitane and Geather's
the search result does not give me the exact result
how can I achieve this ?

Magento Version 2.3.6 and search engine Mysql

Comment: Please add magento version you are using and any search engine if you are using

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar Magento Version 2.3.6 and search engine Mysql